# How to add prefix in mail attribute of AD USER using PowerShell script?

Tags: active-directory

I'm trying to add the prefix **Leaver_** in the mail attribute of AD user using Powershell.
If email is **JSmith@domain.com** it should look like **Leaver_JSmith@domain.com**
Thanks,